# Значение переменной в GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Есть таблица в базе:

```
declare @Results Table
(
    Name Varchar(50), 
    TestResult int 
)

insert into @Results VALUES ('Иван', 5),
                            ('Миша', 3),
                            ('Витя', 3)

select TestResult, COUNT(*) 
from @Results
Group by TestResult
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне необходимо, чтобы в результирующем окне также было указано, что учеников с оценками **2 и 4 равно нулю**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить такой результат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select T.TestResult, COUNT(R.Name) Cnt
from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))T(TestResult)
  left join @Results R on R.TestResult = T.TestResult
Group by T.TestResult

TestResult  Cnt
1   0
2   0
3   2
4   0
5   1
```

Answer (score 2):

В качестве одного из вариантов, можно ввести дополнительную таблицу с оценками

```
create table @Marks (
  value int
);
insert into @Marks values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

Затем воспользоваться `left outer join`

```
select
  m.value,
  COALESCE(r.total, 0)
from
  @Marks m
left outer join
  (select
    TestResult,
    COUNT(*) AS total 
  from @Results 
  Group by TestResult) r
ON
  m.value = r.TestResult;
```

Для тех оценок, для которых нет соответствия в табилце `@Results` возвращается `NULL`, поэтому чтобы получить 0 следует воспользоваться функцией `COALESCE()`.